# Game over popup in Cocos2d v3 iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, layer, cclayer, ccnode

I want to create a Game Over Pop Up, with two buttons and a high score label etc.. This pop up will be visible when the game over event happens and the gameplay scene will be paused.

I tried to implement a game over scene (a separate GameOver class) successfully, but that's not what I want, as it replaces my current gameplay scene and appears on full screen. I want the game over small pop up to appear ON the gameplay scene, while the gameplay scene will be paused (thus indicating game over), and only the game over pop up's buttons will be active.

I think I can achieve this by creating a game over layer (`CCNode` in v3 rather), but I haven't used multiple layers in a Scene yet (as currently I haven't explicitly defined any `CCNode`, just adding children to `self` and everything is working great), also I'm not sure of how can I pause the gameplay only, and let the game over layer (Popup) be active.

Please please guide me with this as this is the only thing left in my game.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/cocos2d-iphone-adding-layers-and-making-simple-pause-screen) article and figured out how to add multiple layers on a single Scene.

Instead of calling `replaceScene` we can just add another layer by

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]; //Pauses current scene
[self addChild:[GameOverNode node]]; //adds the GameOver Layer`

The added layer's buttons remain active while the GamePlay layer is paused. GameOverNode is still another class.

Hope this is helpful for any one who has a similar problem like mine.